# Rails 4.1.0 and authlogic bcrypt issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authlogic, bcrypt

I'm running the latest OSX with rvm ruby 2.1.0. After `bundle update` to Rails 4.1.0 and authlogic 3.4.1, when I start the server I get this error:

```
authlogic/crypto_providers/bcrypt.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- bcrypt (LoadError)
  authlogic-3.4.1/lib/authlogic/crypto_providers/bcrypt.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  authlogic-3.4.1/lib/authlogic.rb:60:in `require'
  authlogic-3.4.1/lib/authlogic.rb:60:in `block in <top (required)>'
  authlogic-3.4.1/lib/authlogic.rb:59:in `each'
  authlogic-3.4.1/lib/authlogic.rb:59:in `<top (required)>'
  bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
  bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
  bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
  bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
  bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
  bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
  bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler.rb:131:in `require'
  application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
  railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `require'
  railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `block in server'
  railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
  railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
  railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
  railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From this [issue](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/issues/400) on the authlogic github account

Authlogic has changed its default encryption system from SHA512 to SCrypt.

It seems that you need this in your gemfile

```
gem 'authlogic', '~> 3.4.0'
gem 'scrypt'
```

If you don't want SCrypt you can use Sha512 by putting this

```
acts_as_authentic do |c|
  c.crypto_provider = Authlogic::CryptoProviders::Sha512
end
```

in your `User.rb`

You also might need to specify the version of the authlogic gem

```
gem 'authlogic', github: 'binarylogic/authlogic', ref: 'e4b2990d6282f3f7b50249b4f639631aef68b939'
```

but I guess this will be fixed soon

Comment: can you tell me what does the `Authlogic::CryptoProviders::Sha512` do in User.rb? What could happen if I don't add it?

Comment: You should try to remove it. Authlogic uses SCrypt by default, but does not have it as a dependency. Thus you have to include scrypt in you gemfile. Use the line`c.crypto_provider = Authlogic::CryptoProviders::Sha512` if you don't want to switch to sCrypt. Read this [here](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/issues/400#issuecomment-36611907) for more info

Comment: Thanks. The problem that i have is that I don't understand what an encryption system does in this gem. If i run the app for 2 week with one encryption and the switch to another, then new users from the 2 last weeks won't be able to login again?

Comment: The password gets encrypted before it gets stored in the database. This way the password is secure and only the user knows it. You can use the helpers in [danlaffan's comment](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/issues/400#issuecomment-36611907) to do the transition to a new encryption system or just keep on using the old one with `c.crypto_provider = Authlogic::CryptoProviders::Sha512`

Comment: okay thanks, I think the situation that I've described can occur